# c++ crashing in a strange way

Tags: multithreading, crash

My problem is that my program crashes in an unusual way. It is a multi-thread program where each thread executes the same loop.
The program starts, it works for 15-20 minutes, then it crashes.
Sometimes I can read on the video output:
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.

What can happen?
The program execute the some loop that terminate after about 1 minute for the 3 thread.

I've looked for some access memory violation (ex. with the array) or for some file opened to write. But There aren't. (I've no global array used by different thread in write, and I've some semaphore for the writing.

Have I to look for some other? I don't know where look for the error.

Comment: "an unusual way" is hardly a descriptive problem definition, and without seeing your code and the actual error message that's happening there's no way someone is going to be able to help you. please look at [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and work on creating a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Start by running in a thread to locate *where* the crash is. Then come back here and edit your question to show some relevant code (and please point out what line the crash happens) and the values of involved variables (and their declarations and initialization).

Comment: Run your program under the debugger.  It might break into the debugger before the termination.  If it does this will give to a chance to examine the program state and try to determine why it is crashing.

Comment: Terminate in an unusual way _normally_ means a C++ exception was thrown and not caught. Its possible this is just a `std::bad_alloc` as you've got memory leaks. Open Task Manager or top and monitor the memory usage - if it grows unbounded its this issue.

Comment: Periodically, have each thread print a message, the message contains the thread number and some descriptive text.  For example, print every minute.  You may to indicate the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` to make debugging easier.  This will also tell you the order of the thread executions.

Comment: The program is not very short, so i can't post all. The memory under the task manager doesn't grow.
If  I start the loop in a single thread I've no problem.
My program download a page, take info, write the on a file and do this since the thing that i've to search are terminated.
The program execute many times the loop for all its lenght, but after n loop it crash.